# I'm looking for a CMS like dotcms but written in PHP

Tags: php, content-management-system

I'm looking for a PHP CMS that works a bit like dotcms. It needs to:

1. Provide the facility to create new content types/structures and surface content from these in modules added to a page.
2. Provide the ability to graphically add and move pre-created modules around a page (moving up/down within the same column is acceptable).
3. Store all code in files on disk so that they can be versioned properly.

Additionally, it needs to place a strong focus on security, accessibility and support friendly URL formats.

I've considered Drupal but would ideally like something that's closer to a CMS than an application  framework. I've also been looking at MODx and SilverStripe but am not sure if they're close enough to my needs.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

For PHP CMS systems that have enterprise capabilities like versioning, custom content types, workflow, buildin multilanguage and multisite, templating engine, scheduling engine, good frameworks etc. you automatically come to these ones: Drupal (good tech base, steep dev learning curve, questionable usability), Typo3 (good tech base, steeper dev learning curve, bad usability), EZ Publish (good tech base, steep learning curve, decent usability), Silverstripe (good tech, shallower learning curve, decent usability).

CMS systems like Expression Engine, Wordpress, MODx etc. are nice, but lack the real big enterprise functionality like versioning, workflow, build-in multisite and multilanguage, custom contenttypes etc.

Olaf

Comment: Silverstripe looks interesting. As far as I can see it doesn't have the visual page configuration of dotcms but in any respects is better as it stores all files (and config) on disk allowing them to be easily versioned. dotcms stores many of the code files in the DB and required webdav to edit the rest (as they stored with non-determinable filenames).

Comment: I spent some time going through Silverstripe tutorials last night. It looks pretty close to what I'm looking for. I think the only thing that's really lacking is a decent interface for adding models/widgets to pages and moving them around.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal with [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views), [CCK](http://drupal.org/project/cck) and [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) should fit your requirements. CCK to create content types, Views to display them and Panels to arrange content on pages.

Drupal is both, a CMS and a framework. I would not rule it out just because of this.

Comment: I've some experience with Drupal but am not that keen on it. Mostly this centers around the level of configuration that's stored in the DB which makes it hard to move developments from dev or staging to live environments. As far as I can see one can solve this to some extent through a custom module utilising the module versioning system but this seems cumbersome. I also don't think that there is a clear enough separation between the frontend of the site and the CMS.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Typo3](http://typo3.org/)

Its a solid extensible php framework widley used in europe.

Comment: I've always found Typo3 hard to get to grips with from a usability point of view. Has it moved on recently?

Comment: with v4.4 backend design looks nicer and its a bit more comfortable to get in, but technically theres nothing really new. Typo3 v5 will be totally revamped from head to feet, but theres still a long way to go... -> http://news.typo3.org/news/teams/typo3-50-development/

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried [Joomla](http://www.joomla.org/) ? Much easier to use than Drupal and extensible by plugins/themes...
Written in PHP/MySQL and offers all the functions you list (directly or by plugins).

Comment: And here is a great tutorial to start you off with developing a component for Joomla if that floats your boat. http://www.joomladevuser.com/tutorials/components